# Multiplayer mode in an Android app

Tags: java, android, multiplayer

So, I am trying to add local multiplayer support for a small app I have built. It is a small game where you get a random letter assigned and then, within a time limit, you must write as many Names as possible that start with that letter. Each one of this Names must belong to a certain Category like Car Brands, Capitals, Countries and so on. I mean, we all played this before. 
I have built the app as a project and it works well if you wanna play alone. But I want to add local multiplayer. I have looked on https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html and as far as i understood there are several ways to do that. I just don´t really know each one i should use.

For context, here is how i imagined the game running on multiplayer:
A player creates a room.
Other players see and join the room.
Room owner starts game.
All play happilly.
Round stops if timer stops or someone stops the timer.
At the end all Names are displayed.
There are more steps at the end but they are irrelevant at the moment.

My question is: from all the material in the link, which one should i use to better realise my game? I know i have to register a service, get players connected and exchange data between them. Each one of the lessons do i have to use? Using Network Service Discovery? Creating P2P Connections with Wi-Fi? or Using Wi-Fi P2P for Service Discovery? Any other ideas?

I am kinda lost! Is there any other way?

Thank you very much

Comment: This is a very broad subject, but if you are going to play over the internet. You could run a WebSocket server (since it seems this will be a realtime game?). That will take care of most of the network related issues for you.

Comment: I am not really going to play over the internet. My idea was to play locally. Send a broadcast, get other players to join the game, play and at the end assign points. A client-server architecture.

Comment: You can use multicast over your LAN to detect other devices running your game. This might help -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: I think this is what I will end up doing. I will use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) as a reference. I will post here when I am done. Thank you